# What is the mapping between psql command line and conninfo for PGConn?

Tags: c, postgresql

Psql command line accepts connection arguments via the short flags -d, -h,-u, p as seen in this documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html

PGConn takes in conninfo strings as seen in the first program of this example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-example.html but this documentation only explains how to specify `dbname` or the `'-d' flag`. How would you make a conninfo string that specifies `-h, -u, and -p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recognized parameter keywords that build connection strings can be found at:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS

To specify "host", "user", and "port":

```
PGConn *conn = PQConnectdb("host=192.168.10.71 user=my-user port=5432 dbname=my-db");
```

Comment: Hi I asked this a while ago and I've made a lot of progress, but I'm wondering if you know how to get the server to force a password prompt from the connection option itself if the server doesn't expect authentication by default